# Is it possible to turn off lock on the file set up by SFTP Session Factory

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I'm struggle with cashed sftp session factory. Namely, I suffered from session unavailable because I used to many in my application. Currently I have one default non cashed session. Which writes file to sftp server but set up locks on them. Thus it can't be read by any other user. I'd like to avoid it. Perfectly, turn off lock after single file is uploaded. Is it possible ?

Test structure

1. Start polling adapter
2. Upload file to remote
3. Check whether files are uploaded
4. Stop polling adapter
5. Clean up remote

Comment: Please, share more specific info, including some code to reproduce. Spring Integration does not set any locks on those files. Perhaps you mean not closed an `InputStream` after you call `SftpSession.write(InputStream inputStream, String destination)`...

Comment: That is not a case. I'm using `public String send(Message<?> message, String subDirectory, FileExistsMode... mode)`. And everything seems to work fine with the cashing turned off. When I enable it. Tests fail on deletion of earlier uploaded file. I'm getting not very descriptive error  `SFTP error (SSH_FX_FAILURE): General failure
java.io.UncheckedIOException: SFTP error (SSH_FX_FAILURE): General failure`. My initial guess was that session is not closed. Thus files are blocked for an operation. Can you maybe give me advice how to debug it even better ?

Comment: See logging for JSCH to better understand what is going on: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-jsch-logging. We recommended caching all the time. So, something is off on your server side.

Comment: Hey @ArtemBilan you were right. I did not close InputStream :// I missed it. Thanks so much for your time and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deal with data transferring over the network, you need to be sure that you release resources you use do to that. For example be sure to close `InputStream` after sending data to the SFTP. This is really not a framework responsibility to close it automatically. More over you may give us already not an `InputStream`, but just plain `byte[]` from it. That's only a reason I can think about locking-like behavior.